# RabbitMQ Problem loading page (connection reset bad header GET/FAV)

Tags: linux, server, rabbitmq

rabbitmq has connected to my ports and everything looks good so far but when i try to connect to my localhost in browser im getting this error message:

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web
```

so the first thing i did was go and look at my rabbitmq log and i see this:

```
 Starting RabbitMQ 3.7.9 on Erlang 20.2.2
 Copyright (C) 2007-2018 Pivotal Software, Inc.
 Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
2019-09-15 08:06:51.710 [info] <0.240.0> 
 node           : rabbit@bowzer
 home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
 config file(s) : (none)
 cookie hash    : XC8syc3LUBiQChoU4UJxPA==
 log(s)         : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@bowzer.log
                : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@bowzer_upgrade.log
 database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@bowzer
2019-09-15 08:06:52.982 [info] <0.248.0> Memory high watermark set to 6421 MiB (6733540556 bytes) of 16054 MiB (16833851392 bytes) total
2019-09-15 08:06:52.987 [info] <0.250.0> Enabling free disk space monitoring
2019-09-15 08:06:52.987 [info] <0.250.0> Disk free limit set to 50MB
2019-09-15 08:06:52.991 [info] <0.253.0> Limiting to approx 32668 file handles (29399 sockets)
2019-09-15 08:06:52.991 [info] <0.254.0> FHC read buffering:  OFF
2019-09-15 08:06:52.991 [info] <0.254.0> FHC write buffering: ON
2019-09-15 08:06:52.993 [info] <0.240.0> Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left
2019-09-15 08:06:53.164 [info] <0.240.0> Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left
2019-09-15 08:06:53.164 [info] <0.240.0> Peer discovery backend rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config does not support registration, skipping registration.
2019-09-15 08:06:53.165 [info] <0.240.0> Priority queues enabled, real BQ is rabbit_variable_queue
2019-09-15 08:06:53.219 [info] <0.278.0> Starting rabbit_node_monitor
2019-09-15 08:06:53.241 [info] <0.306.0> Making sure data directory '/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@bowzer/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L' for vhost '/' exists
2019-09-15 08:06:53.302 [info] <0.306.0> Starting message stores for vhost '/'
2019-09-15 08:06:53.303 [info] <0.310.0> Message store "628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_transient": using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index
2019-09-15 08:06:53.305 [info] <0.306.0> Started message store of type transient for vhost '/'
2019-09-15 08:06:53.306 [info] <0.313.0> Message store "628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_persistent": using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index
2019-09-15 08:06:53.308 [info] <0.306.0> Started message store of type persistent for vhost '/'
2019-09-15 08:06:53.312 [warning] <0.334.0> Setting Ranch options together with socket options is deprecated. Please use the new map syntax that allows specifying socket options separately from other options.
2019-09-15 08:06:53.313 [info] <0.348.0> started TCP listener on [::]:5672
2019-09-15 08:06:53.314 [info] <0.240.0> Setting up a table for connection tracking on this node: tracked_connection_on_node_rabbit@bowzer
2019-09-15 08:06:53.314 [info] <0.240.0> Setting up a table for per-vhost connection counting on this node: tracked_connection_per_vhost_on_node_rabbit@bowzer
2019-09-15 08:06:53.315 [info] <0.33.0> Application rabbit started on node rabbit@bowzer
2019-09-15 08:06:53.375 [notice] <0.86.0> Changed loghwm of /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@bowzer.log to 50
2019-09-15 08:06:53.540 [info] <0.5.0> Server startup complete; 0 plugins started.
2019-09-15 08:10:51.196 [info] <0.378.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.378.0> (127.0.0.1:55986 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
2019-09-15 08:10:51.196 [error] <0.378.0> closing AMQP connection <0.378.0> (127.0.0.1:55986 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{bad_header,<<"GET / HT">>}
2019-09-15 08:13:26.916 [info] <0.385.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.385.0> (127.0.0.1:55990 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
2019-09-15 08:13:26.916 [error] <0.385.0> closing AMQP connection <0.385.0> (127.0.0.1:55990 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{bad_header,<<"GET / HT">>}
2019-09-15 08:13:27.007 [info] <0.389.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.389.0> (127.0.0.1:55992 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
2019-09-15 08:13:27.007 [error] <0.389.0> closing AMQP connection <0.389.0> (127.0.0.1:55992 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{bad_header,<<"GET /fav">>}
```

so i went and checked my ports and i get this:

sudo lsof -i -p -n | grep rabbitmq:

```
epmd      5687        rabbitmq    3u  IPv4  59822      0t0  TCP *:4369 (LISTEN)

epmd      5687        rabbitmq    4u  IPv6  59823      0t0  TCP *:4369 (LISTEN)

beam.smp  5892        rabbitmq   59u  IPv4  57068  0t0  TCP *:25672 (LISTEN)

beam.smp  5892        rabbitmq   69u  IPv6  58166      0t0  TCP *:5672 (LISTEN)
```

sudo service rabbitmq-server status:

```
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset:
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-09-15 07:53:32 MST; 2min 19s ago
 Main PID: 875 (beam.smp)
   Status: "Initialized"
    Tasks: 90 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rabbitmq-server.service
           ├─ 875 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-9.2/bin/beam.smp -W w -A 64 -P 1048576 -t 500000
           ├─1037 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-9.2/bin/epmd -daemon
           ├─1387 erl_child_setup 32768
           ├─1691 inet_gethost 4
           └─1692 inet_gethost 4

Sep 15 07:53:27 bowzer rabbitmq-server[875]:   ##  ##
Sep 15 07:53:27 bowzer rabbitmq-server[875]:   ##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.7.9. Copyright (C
Sep 15 07:53:27 bowzer rabbitmq-server[875]:   ##########  Licensed under the MPL.  See
Sep 15 07:53:27 bowzer rabbitmq-server[875]:   ######  ##
Sep 15 07:53:27 bowzer rabbitmq-server[875]:   ##########  Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabb
Sep 15 07:53:27 bowzer rabbitmq-server[875]:                     /var/log/rabbitmq/rabb
Sep 15 07:53:27 bowzer rabbitmq-server[875]:               Starting broker...
Sep 15 07:53:32 bowzer rabbitmq-server[875]: systemd unit for activation check: "rabbit
Sep 15 07:53:32 bowzer systemd[1]: Started RabbitMQ broker.
Sep 15 07:53:33 bowzer rabbitmq-server[875]:  completed with 0 plugins.
```

i also noticed that when others download and install the server they get 'completed with 6 plugins' and mine started with 0 plugins.

Answer (score 9):

Your browser is trying to talk **HTTP** on **port 5672** which is the **AMQP** port of the RabbitMQ broker.

If you want to access the management console, enable the [management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) and access it on http://your-rabbitmq-host:15672/.